# $http.get in angularjs reads txt file but could not read json file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, visual-studio

I'm new to `angularjs` and I am trying to read data from `json` file using `$http.get` method but couldn't read it.

When I tried to read a simple `txt` file using `$http.get` it reads normally.

I can't understand where I am going wrong...

Here is my code :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Plunkr.aspx.cs" Inherits="AngularJS.Plunkr" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
      <title>content</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

          angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.json = 'Cities not yet loaded.';
                $http.get('read.txt') //when I try to read cities.json error occurs
                  .then(function (data) {
                      debugger;
                      $scope.json = data.data;
                  }, function (error) {
                      debugger;
                      alert('error');
                  });
            })
          ;
    </script>
  </head>

  <body data-ng-controller="myController">
    <p>JSON content should display below here:</p>
    <pre>{{json}}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

`read.txt` file simply contains `Hello world` string.

When I try to read `json` file `then()` executes **error function**.

When I hovered over `error` variable it gave me `status` as `404` and `statusText` as `Not Found`

Here is `json` file cities.json

```
    {
  "cities": [
    {   
        "city": "Pune", 
        "latitud": "1", 
        "longitud": "2",
        "id": "pun"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Mumbai", 
        "latitud": "45", 
        "longitud": "23",
        "id": "mum"
    },
    {
        "city": "Delhi", 
        "latitud": "22", 
        "longitud": "676",
        "id": "del"
    },
    {
        "city": "Chennai", 
        "latitud": "45", 
        "longitud": "787",
        "id": "del"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using `Visual Studio` as `IDE`

I found this example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KrHjANUvWsiDBaBLLRIT?p=preview) and it runs perfectly there.

Comment: I cannot undersatnd what the error is with the JSON file

Comment: Yea it sounds like something is wrong with your endpoint not your json file.

Answer (score 0):

I have run this code successfully without any error, you can see working [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/O9FNpQmBBS4T3cMrvBUF?p=preview)

If it still doesn’t fulfil you requirement,please elaborate your problem with the updated code.

Comment: It runs when we pass text file as a parameter to `$http.get()` but it fails when we pass `json` file

Comment: it runs good as well with readfile.json http://plnkr.co/edit/O9FNpQmBBS4T3cMrvBUF?p=preview

Comment: can you share your json file,or else console your prommise result data,whats error you are getting there

Comment: hey, I found out the error. It wasn't in my code. I had to configure my IIS again to solve the error